# Dagger2 cuando usarlo y cuando no

Tags: android, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y usamos Dagger2. Me pregunto si es recomendable usarlo en todas nuestras clases para evitar hacer `new` al instanciarlas. Por lo que estoy leyendo solo es necesario cuando la instancia de objeto [se crea en el constructor.](https://erikcaffrey.github.io/2016/04/26/dependency-injection/)

```
public class WeatherForecaster {

  private final LocationService locationService;

  public WeatherForecaster() {
    this.locationService = new LocationService();
  }
}
```

Mi duda es usando una clase como esta, por ejemplo:

```
public class SocialControler{

private ImageView twitterLogo;
private ImageView googleLogo;

public SocialControler(ImageView twitter, ImageView google){
twitterLogo = twitter;
googleLogo = google;
}
//Getters and Setters

}
```

Cuando instancio la clase en mi `Activity` tengo algo como:

```
SocialControler mSocial = new SocialControler(mTwitterLogo, mGoogleLogo);
```

¿Es necesario inyectar la clase `SocialControler` (que no construye ningún objeto en su constructor) en mi `Activity`sin hacer `new` mediante la anotación `@inject`?